# Is it better to use nesting or multiple files?

Tags: xml, file, nested

Which is the better approach, to nest, or have multiple files with "IDs" that "link" the different files?

Here are my examples that I am working with:

**Multiple files:**

- [company.xml](https://gist.github.com/1042786)
- [branches.xml](https://gist.github.com/1042787)
- [years.xml](https://gist.github.com/1042788)
- [months.xml](https://gist.github.com/1042790)

**Nested:**

- [company_nested.xml](https://gist.github.com/1042792)

First time at XML, so it could be horribly wrong! (and I am planning to make XSD's as soon as I have some idea of where the structure is going).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both approaches have their place; it really depends on how the data will be used. Using a single file is great if you're primarily going to process the data with XSLT. If, on the other hand, you're just using XML as a persistence mechanism for an object tree, the separate files let you rewrite just the parts of interest without affecting the whole file.

Comment: My original speculations were correct then! Persistence is what I am after. I would just like to know if the structure of the multiple files in the example above is okay for what I would like to do?

Comment: Seems fine to me, yes. Now, you should be aware that many programming ecosystems have their own pre-made XML-based persistence tools available, and those packages often like to determine the XML format themselves. You probably want to at least investigate such a package for the language you're using, and decide whether it wouldn't be better to just leave the XML behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you are trying to achieve. Without any knowledge of project requirements or constraints, no one can say whether one design is better than another.